# Infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-3)^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can show that the sum $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-3)^n}{n!}\;$ converges. But I do not see why the limit should be $\dfrac{1}{e^3}$.

How do I calculate the limit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint:
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Ok, that was too easy to see. I spend an hour on this, without see the result. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @leo It happens to best of us.

Comment: Yes, it happens to the best. But the best don't give up after just one hour. -:)

Answer (score 11):

**Hints**:

- $\quad$You'll want to [remember](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29#Complex_numbers): $\quad \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$
- $\quad$For any $a, b,\;$ (provided $a\ne 0$):$\quad\displaystyle a^{-b} = \frac{1}{a^b}$

---

Comment: Thank you! A helpful addition to the answer of @Nameless. But I did know this fact already.

Comment: 15K! So far away from me!

Comment: @Sigur - take heart! rep is just a number; my posts now are not much different (in terms of quality) than my posts when I was below 2k.